Filter by categories using checkboxes in dropdowns on Webflow
Read-only link: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/wholeselfcare-004df4?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=wholeselfcare-004df4&preview=69ca36c72b9a25ea516c244822f15c37&pageId=662910567b444c6755f4afc6&itemId=67664dd8f1a99636ae4c3c07&locale=en&workflow=preview
Hello, I'm using finsweet to set up a filter by category for a client's site featuring a directory of ~225 listings; these should be filterable by clicking checkboxes in 4 dropdowns:
country (9 items)
session type (2 items)
client type (2 items)
specialty (2 items)
I have set everything up (menu, dropdown, check boxes, layout of collection list); the one thing I am struggling with is the actual filter function.
I have watched YT and Webflow University videos, but the site is still not filtering when I click the checkboxes. Could anyone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
